# Only able to send email when connected to VPN

Tags: email, vpn

I use mutt for email and msmtp for sending email from my Linux machine. However, for a long time, I have I had the issue that emails will only send (from an Outlook email address) when I am on particular networks. This is true in particular of my school network, so I am able to send email when I connect to my school's VPN.

What could be causing this? Is there a way to repair things so that I no longer need to use a VPN to send email?

Thanks

Comment: In Outlook Email Accounts, More Settings, make sure the Outgoing Server matches  network settings you are sending from.  That should do it for you.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for your help! Feel free to make your comment an answer.

Comment: I did as you suggested.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you need here, in Outlook Email Accounts, More Settings, make sure the Outgoing Server matches network settings you are sending from.

That should do it for you.